Automorphism group of a direct product of directly indecomposable centerless groups.
I know that if $G$ and $H$ are two arbitrary groups $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ is not isomorphic in general to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$, in fact $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ can have infinite index in $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ when dealing with infinite groups.
In wikipedia I read that when $G$ and $H$ are directly indecomposable centerless groups $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)\cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ iff $G\ncong H$ and $ \mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ has index $2$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ iff $G\cong H$. It says that it is part of the Krull–Schmidt theorem, however it looks something that should be easy to prove directly.
Do you have any references for a direct proof of this fact?
